# Why does System V shared memory have separate get and attach functions?

Tags: unix, posix, ipc, shared-memory

Using System V shared memory IPC requires calls to the following two functions:

```
int shmget(key_t key, size_t size, int shmflg);
void *shmat(int shmid, const void *shmaddr, int shmflg);
```

Why are they designed to be separate, instead of having a single function that accepts these arguments, performs both functions and simply returns the address?

We can consider files as an analogy. `open` on a string (the file path) gives us a file descriptor, and we use that to read/write from the file. We `close` on the file descriptor when we're done. This design seems natural, we don't have to `open` with a string to get a descriptor, and then `attach` to the descriptor.

As an example of what I have in mind, take a look at the [FreeBSD sendmail shared memory implementation](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-head/blob/master/contrib/sendmail/libsm/shm.c).

This kind of separation (`shm_open` and `mmap`) also exists with POSIX shared memory, but the reason was that `mmap` existed before `shm_open` was implemented and could be reused, and `mmap` requires a descriptor (source: UNIX Network Programming Vol. 2, R. Stevens, chapter 13, page 326).

Answer (score 0):

Shared memory is probably one of the fastest ways of allowing for IPC as data need not be copied, the problem associated with it though is synchronizing access between multiple threads. You could do this using semaphores or record locks , we end up using the later in unix fro shared memory even though they are not as efficient as they are simple, the system cleans up well, and you don't need some of the bling that semaphores bring along. 
Lets look into how these work to understand why they are implemented as such.

In comes the shmid_ds used by the linux kernel (http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node68.html)
the shm_nattch is the unsigned int counter for current attaches. shmget gets you an shm id and sets stuff like the ipc_perm , dates, pid, atime ctime, request of the segment size (shm_segsz)
next the shmctl kicks in and does stuff for ipc using IPC_STAT, IPC_RMID, IPC_SET like setting perms, getting or removing shm_id for a segment or even locking or unlocking it.

Once the segment is ready shmat is used by a process to attach to its address space, depending on the flags and address parameters. Once it attaches the kernel increments the shm_nattch. When detaching we call shmdt to detach . Removal of the identifier and the associated data structure is not automated some process has to do this calling shmctl with the IPC_RMID and depending on shm_perm

As you can see this is all very similar to how one would use semaphores and the implementation makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason I could think of is this: 
(From the [manpage of shmget](http://www.ms.sapientia.ro/~lszabo/oprendszer1/man_en/htmlman2/shmget.2.html))

> - After a fork(2) the child inherits the attached shared memory    segments.
> - After an execve(2) all attached shared memory segments    are detached from the process.
> - Upon _exit(2) all attached shared    memory segments are detached from the process.

Well, technically attaching and detaching is basic reference counting on the shared memory segment that is reserved during shmget.

The functionalities of allocating the shared memory segment, via shmget and reference counting them (up or down, via shmat and shmdt respectively), are separate so that, code can be reused during fork and exec.

If they were both packed into the same function, you would anyways need a separate function, which just does reference counting (to be invoked during fork/exec). So, I think this design is simply to promote code reuse, and avoid code duplication.

Comment: For the case of files, `fork` and `exec` handle copying the file descriptors and updating reference counts within the kernel. There is no "attach" for files. Why is `shmat` exposed to the user, when it could be done within the kernel just like files?